# "out of memory" error for mvregress in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression, multivariate-testing

I am trying to use mvregress with the data I have with dimensionality of a couple of hundreds. (3~4). Using 32 gb of ram, I can not compute beta and I get "out of memory" message. I couldn't find any limitation of use for mvregress that prevents me to apply it on vectors with this degree of dimensionality, am I doing something wrong? is there any way to use multivar linear regression via my data?

here is an example of what goes wrong:

```
dim=400;
nsamp=1000;
dataVariance = .10;
noiseVariance = .05;
mixtureCenters=randn(dim,1);
X=randn(dim, nsamp)*sqrt(dataVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,nsamp);
N=randn(dim, nsamp)*sqrt(noiseVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,nsamp);
A=2*eye(dim);
Y=A*X+N;
%without residual term:
A_hat=mvregress(X',Y');
%wit residual term:
[B, y_hat]=mlrtrain(X,Y)
```

where

```
function [B, y_hat]=mlrtrain(X,Y)
[n,d] = size(Y);
Xmat = [ones(n,1) X];
Xmat_sz=size(Xmat);
Xcell = cell(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    Xcell{i} = [kron([Xmat(i,:)],eye(d))];
end
[beta,sigma,E,V] = mvregress(Xcell,Y);
B = reshape(beta,d,Xmat_sz(2))';
y_hat=Xmat * B ;
end
```

---

the error is:

```
Error using bsxfun
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in kron (line 36)
   K = reshape(bsxfun(@times,A,B),[ma*mb na*nb]);

Error in mvregress (line 319)
            c{j} = kron(eye(NumSeries),Design(j,:));
```

and this is result of whos command:

```
whos
  Name                  Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A                   400x400             1280000  double              
  N                   400x1000            3200000  double              
  X                   400x1000            3200000  double              
  Y                   400x1000            3200000  double              
  dataVariance          1x1                     8  double              
  dim                   1x1                     8  double              
  mixtureCenters      400x1                  3200  double              
  noiseVariance         1x1                     8  double              
  nsamp                 1x1                     8  double
```

Comment: Just to make sure there is nothing wrong with your matlab installation or system, you are running a 64bit version of matlab and `memory` prints the information that at least large parts of your memory can be used?

Comment: @Daniel that's correct. I can see that my memory as well as my swap, both  go up to 32 gb (in sum, 64 gb) then the code fails.

Comment: I haven't read carefully to figure out `kron([Xmat(i,:)],eye(d))` is trying to do, but each call generates a 1000 by 1001000 sized matrix, that is, an 8 gigabyte datastructure. Your call to mvregress then ends up trying to estimate 1001000 regression coefficients from 400 observations (which is not possible). This is probably not what you want?

Comment: @MatthewGunn well, i wasn't quite sure whether i should use mvregress as i used in the commented line, or as i used in the function. in an example I found on matlab help (which adds that row of ones), it uses kron the same way. what i wanna do is to learn a matrix beta which projects $X$ to $Y$. i also tried the commented line, but same problem. My data is 400 dimensional and I have 1000 samples.

Comment: Anoosh, from your answer to Daniel's question, it is unclear whether you looked up the correct value. It is not the amount of system memory that you can see in the task manager. Please type the 'memory' command in the MATLAB command window, it should look something like this:
>> memory
Maximum possible array:              12699 MB (1.332e+010 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     12699 MB (1.332e+010 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:                 710 MB (7.445e+008 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):                8098 MB (8.491e+009 bytes)

Comment: @Douba the memory command is not available in Linux:
Error using memory
Function MEMORY is not available on this platform.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea. Could you maybe provide the result of 'whos' in the state when the error occurs? We would get a clue on the order of magnitude of the needed space. I take it that it occurs within the function, yes? And I take n there to equal 400, right? There might be a few points where you could save memory.

Comment: @Douba If you have access to matlab, you can simply use the sample code above. The error occurs inside the function, so I am not sure how it helps since I don't have access to the variables inside mvregress matlab function. and yes, n, the number of variables, is 400. I will update the question with what you asked.

Comment: Thank you, Anoosh. I am trying it out right now. You can gain access to some function's workspaces by typing 'dbstop if error', this enables you to debug errors. Other useful commands: 'dbclear if error' to disable this behavior, 'dbstack' to display the call stack, and 'dbup' and 'dbdown' to switch between stacked workspaces.

Comment: @Douba thank you! that was some useful information. I hope you can find the problem!

Comment: It would help others help you if you *specifically* state the regression equation you're trying to estimate.

Comment: I don't understand `N=randn(dim, nsamp)*sqrt(noiseVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,nsamp);` The noise isn't mean zero? Sounds like a misspecified model?

Comment: @matthew-gunn the noise has a different Gaussian distribution than the observations. This is just a toy example though.

Comment: A classic assumption of linear regression models is strict exogeneity, that E[e|X] = 0. Given your setup with (supposed to be an error term?) N having a non-zero mean, you're not going to estimate A consistently unless you reframe the problem as one satisfying strict exogeneiety (eg. by adding an indicator variable for each mixture to capture the mixture specific mean).

Comment: If you want n = nsamp and d = dim, you almost certainly want `[B, y_hat]=mlrtrain(X',Y')` instead of your current `[B, y_hat]=mlrtrain(X,Y)`

Comment: @MatthewGunn that's right. they should be transposed as it is in my example.

Comment: @Anoosh I suggest you examine the code I just posted. At least for your test example, the efficient way to calculate OLS estimate is simply call the blackslash operator, which as I show, is equivalent in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I think I have a solution for you, short version first:

```
dim=400;
nsamp=1000;
dataVariance = .10;
noiseVariance = .05;
mixtureCenters=randn(dim,1);
X=randn(dim, nsamp)*sqrt(dataVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,nsamp);
N=randn(dim, nsamp)*sqrt(noiseVariance ) + repmat(mixtureCenters,1,nsamp);
A=2*eye(dim);
Y=A*X+N;

[n,d] = size(Y);
Xmat = [ones(n,1) X];
Xmat_sz=size(Xmat);
Xcell = cell(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    Xcell{i} = kron(Xmat(i,:),speye(d));
end
[beta,sigma,E,V] = mvregress(Xcell,Y);
B = reshape(beta,d,Xmat_sz(2))';
y_hat=Xmat * B ;
```

Strangely, I could not access the function's workspace, it did not appear in the call stack. This is why I put the function after the script here.

Here's the explanation that might also help you in the future:
Looking at the `kron` definition, the result when inserting an m by n and a p by q matrix has size mxp by nxq, in your case 400 by 1001 and 1000 by 1000, that makes a 400000 by 1001000 matrix, which has 4*10^11 elements. Now you have four hundred of them, and each element takes up 8 bytes for double precision, that is a total size of about 1.281 Petabytes of memory (or 1.138 Pebibytes, if you prefer), well out of reach even with your grand 32 Gibibyte.

Seeing that one of your matrices, the eye one, contains mostly zeros, and the resulting matrix contains all possible element product combinations, most of them will be zero, too. For such cases specifically, MATLAB offers the sparse matrix format, which saves a lot of memory depending on the number of zero elements in a matrix by only storing nonzero ones. You can convert a full matrix to a sparse representation with `sparse(X)`, or you get an eye matrix directly by using `speye(n)`, which is what I did above. The sparse property propagates to the result, which you should now have enough memory for (I have with 1/4 of your memory available, and it works).

However, what remains is the problem Matthew Gunn mentioned in a comment. I get an error saying:

Error using mvregress (line 260)
Insufficient data to estimate either full or least-squares models.

Comment: that was a smart trick! but unfortunately, didn't find the answer. so basically, we need more observations to be able to find the solution. If we increase the observation size, again more memory is needed. 
Is there any way to find out how much memory is needed to solve this problem?

What if we directly use A_hat=mvregress(X',Y');? can it be optimized?

Comment: @Anoosh You might consider dimensionality reduction techniques instead of keeping all 400 regressors. This paper considers [Sufficient dimension reduction in multivariate regressions with categorical predictors](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947313000583). It probably references s more generic example.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe for the actual mathematical/algorithmic problem you are trying to accomplish, you could ask another question on the appropriate board. The memory problem per se seems to be solved, right?

Comment: Almost certainly there's a matrix transposition error, that is, there should be an `X = X'; Y = Y'` before you do the Xcell stuff. n should be equivalent to nsamp and d should be equivalent to dim. And this is why it says insufficient data to estimate the model and adding observations seems to make it worse (because in some sense you have observations and regressors mixed up).

Answer (score 2):

#### Preface

If your regressors are all the same across each regression equation and you're interested in the OLS estimate, you can replace a call to mvregress with a simple call to `\`.

It appears in the call to `mlrtrain` you had a matrix transposition error (since corrected). In the language of mvregress, n is the number of observations, d is the number of outcome variables. You generate a matrix Y that is d by n. But THEN when you should call mlrtrain(X', Y') not mlrtrain(X, Y).

If below isn't specifically, what you're looking for, I suggest you precisely define what you're trying to estimate.

#### What I would have written if I were you

So much that's been said here is completely off base that I'm posting code of what I would have written if I were you. I've reduced the dimensionality to show the equivalence in your special case to simply calling `\`. I've also written stuff in a more standard way (i.e. having observations run down the rows and not making matrix transposition errors).

```
dim=5;              % These can go way higher but only if you use my code 
nsamp=20;           % rather than call mvregress
dataVariance = .10;
noiseVariance = .05;
mixtureCenters=randn(dim,1);

X = randn(nsamp, dim)*sqrt(dataVariance )  + repmat(mixtureCenters', nsamp, 1); %'
E = randn(nsamp, dim)*sqrt(noiseVariance);   %noise should be mean zero
B = 2*eye(dim);
Y = X*B+E;
% without constant:
B_hat  = mvregress(X,Y);     %<-------- slow, blows up with high dimension
B_hat2 = X \ Y;              %<-------- fast, fine with higher dimensions

norm(B_hat - B_hat2)         % show numerical equivalent if basically 0

% with constant:
B_constant_hat  = mlrtrain(X,Y)       %<-------- slow, blows up with high dimension
B_constant_hat2 = [ones(nsamp, 1), X] \ Y; % <-- fast, and fine with higher dimensions

norm(B_constant_hat - B_constant_hat2)         % show numerical equivalent if basically 0
```

#### Explanation

I'll assume you have:

- An `nsamp` by `dim` sized data matrix `X`.
- An `nsamp` by `ny` sized matrix of outcome variables `Y`
- You want the results from regressing each column of `Y` on data matrix `X`. That is, we're doing multivariate regression but there's a common data matrix X.

That is, we're estimating:

```
y_{ij} = \sum_k b_k * x_{ik} + e_{ijk} for i=1...nsamp, j = 1...ny, k=1...dim
```

If you're trying to do something different than this, you need to clearly state what you're trying to do!

To regress `Y` on `X` you could do:

```
[beta_mvr, sigma_mvr, resid_mvr] = mvregress(X, Y);
```

This appears to be horribly slow. The following should match mvregress for the case where you're using the same data matrix for each regression.

```
beta_hat  = X \ Y;            % estimate beta using least squares
resid     = Y - X * beta_hat;     % calculate residual
```

If you want to construct a new data matrix with a vector of ones, you would do:

```
X_withones = [ones(nsamp, 1), X];
```

#### Further clarification for some that are confused

Let's say we want to run the regression

```
y_i = \sum_j x_{ij} + e_i  i=1...n, j=1...k
```

We can construct the data matrix n by k datamatrix X and an n by 1 outcome vector y. The OLS estimate is `bhat = pinv(X' * X) * X' * y` which can also be computed in MATLAB with `bhat = X \ y`.

If you want to do this multiple times (i.e. run multivariate regression on the same data matrix X), you can construct an outcome matrix Y where EACH column represents a separate outcome variable. Y = [ya, yb, yc, ...]. Trivially, the OLS solution is `B = pinv(X'*X)*X'*Y` which can be computed as `B = X \ Y`. The first column of B is the result of regressing Y(:,1) on X. The second column of B is the result of regressing Y(:,2) on X, etc...  Under these conditions, this is equivalent to a call to B = mvregress(X, Y)

#### Even more test code

If regressors are the same and estimation is by simple OLS, there is an equivalence between multivariate regression and equation by equation ordinary least squares.

```
d = 10;
k = 15;
n = 100;

C = RandomCorr(d + k, 1);  %Use any method you like to generate a random correlation matrix
s = randn(d+k , 1) * 10;
S = (s * s') .* C;         % generate covariance matrix

mu = randn(d+k,1);

data = mvnrnd(ones(n, 1) * mu', S);

Y = data(:,1:d);
X = data(:,d+1:end);

[b1, sigma] = mvregress(X, Y);
b2 = X \ Y;

norm(b1 - b2)
```

You will notice b1 and b2 are numerically equivalent. They are equivalent even though sigma is EXTREMELY different from zero.

Comment: If I am not wrong, your approach is called normal equation: beta = pinv(X' * X) * X' * y; What I am not sure is that this approach was equal to multiple regression or multivariate regression. Because my response vector y are correlated.

Comment: @Anoosh If you're doing ordinary least squares (i.e. not trying to boost efficiency by using covariance structure of residuals) then that is what you get.

Comment: Multivariate regression, not to be confounded with _multivariable_, estimates the joint probability distribution of all `Y_i` and `X_i`, and hence is fundamentally different from the simple linear regression with one `y` and many regressors `X`. For reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_regression or Greene's Econometrics book. That's why no one is questioning the intent of the OP and his question sounds legit. Also, we do not have enough info to judge wether the method is appropriate nor such question belong to SO.

Comment: Also, Anoosh's snippets of code are basically extracts from `mvregress()`. I am actually surprised that TheMathworks has not considered building a sparse matrix in the first place (see inner code of mvregress), and should be forwarded as an enhancement to the function.

Comment: You might have missed that Anoosh has provided a dummy example with iid samples and that his real data is correlated. Again, this is well explained in Greene, a multivariate regression is exactly n linear regressions IFF the Y_i are uncorrelated. I also suggest you refrain from colourful language.

Comment: Actually your answer would be on point If you edited out all of the polemic parts and specified  that in te absence of correlation among Y, as it seems to be the case with provided example, the solution is equivalent to n independent linear regressions.

Comment: @Oleg Correlation among Y doesn't matter. Under conditions I have specified, my code is clearly equivalent to a call to mvregress, as you can verify yourself. If you review Chapter 10.2.2 of Green, perhaps you will understand why. I regret if you interpreted my comments as hostility. Best of luck.

Comment: The op does return inside the mltrain function, the covariance matrix. Maybe he's not showing code that uses it. There was no need for luck in that. And yes, usually swear words or 'rant' imply some degree of hostility age frustration whic were unnecessary. I also removed the down vote since your edits.

Comment: @Oleg and matthew-gunn the example code I provided is a toy example try to mimic my real problem. I am not looking for find the simple A I created in this question using only simple Gaussian observations. In my real problem, my Y are correlated and I need to be able to use mvregress. Even though I was aware of the solution matthew provided which was not my purpose to ask this question. What Douba did, was a nice trick which I might be able to use by modifying mvregress and write my own function out of it.

Comment: mvregress is able to provide more advanced solutions rather than only a multiple linear assumption. My problem at the beginning was inefficiency of mvregress function.